# Mystery times conversion (pandas and datetime)

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

Can anyone explain this?

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime
pd.to_datetime(1532329236726000, unit="us")
```

returns `Timestamp('2018-07-23 07:00:36.726000')`

```
datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 23, 8, 0, 36, 726000).timestamp() * 10**6
```

returns `1532329236726000.0`.

So, is `1532329236726000` 2018-07-23 07:00:36 or 2018-07-23 08:00:36 ?

Comment: I think you should try it again. I just did `>>> datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 23, 8, 0, 36, 726000).timestamp() * 10**6` and got 1532354436726000.0

Comment: Ok, so why does it depends on the computer then?

Comment: It shouldn't. What version of Python are you using?

Comment: `sys.version_info(major=3, minor=5, micro=2, releaselevel='final', serial=0)`

Comment: Can't reproduce your error.

Comment: Well I noticed this at work, so there's at least two computers on this planet that behave like this. I suspected that might be more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will depend on the timezone info of the datetime object you create. YOu are in fact creating a naive timezone object in both cases which does not have a specific timezone set

`datetime.datetime()` objects may assume a local timezone as opposed to UTC which your `pd.to_datetime()` assumes

`datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 23, 7, 0, 36, 726000).replace(tzinfo=pytz.utc).timestamp() * 10**6` returns the same epoch time you put into your original question

From the python docs

"A naive object does not contain enough information to unambiguously locate itself relative to other date/time objects. Whether a naive object represents Coordinated Universal Time (UTC), local time, or time in some other timezone is purely up to the program, just like it is up to the program whether a particular number represents metres, miles, or mass. Naive objects are easy to understand and to work with, at the cost of ignoring some aspects of reality."

https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html

You can explicitly tell both functions in your answer to use UTC with a kwarg to the constructors (and without using `pytz` as below)

`datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 23, 7, 0, 36, 726000, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)`

`pd.to_datetime(1532329236726000, unit="us", utc=True)`

Comment: I suspected it might be something to do with timezone. However I still don't get it. That datetime object doesn't know about timezone. pandas.to_datetime does't know about timezone. So how does the discrepancy appear?

Comment: Because they are both assuming different timezones. See the python docs I linked to. 

The timezone in both cases isn't explicitly determined. For example on my python program, `pandas.to_datetime()` seems to give me UTC and `datetime.datetime()` seems to assume local time.

Comment: So is there a way to explicitely tell the constructor to assume UTC on instantiation, as opposed to having to call `.replace` and use the external module `pytz`?

Comment: Yes its a `tzinfo` kwarg of the constructor so `datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 23, 7, 0, 36, 726000, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)` will work

Comment: Probably cleaner

Comment: For pandas you can use `pd.to_datetime(1532329236726000, unit="us", utc=True)`

Comment: Fantastic. Please add those two last comments to the answer.

Comment: Although.... This way I end up with two aware objects. I'd prefer working with naive objects.

Comment: You can't compare two naive datetime objects and expect to get consistent results unfortunately

Comment: I'm still confused, actually. I just want to obtain the number of microseconds between epoch and right now. Note, no timezones involved. What is the correct way to do that?

Comment: So unless you define a timezone that is not well defined, you can't do this consistently and expect the same results. See the link I posted in my answer